# Paypal donaton form with muticheck option

Tags: wordpress

I want a functionality in WordPress that some one select multiple option and than press the donate button for checkout in paypal?
Any one know this type of plugin name?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-donations/

Comment: i did that with wpforms plugin, thanks